# Converting a project from webforms to MVC over time - can this be done?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a typical 3-tiered webforms app backed by a SQL server database. In addition, several of the forms call a DAL layer that gets data from a DB2 database on a host, and this logic is well encapsulated. There are about 80 forms in this project but I'd say at least 50 of them are so similar that they would share the same 2 or 3 views.

So tell me if you think this is a recipe for disaster...I've been asked to explore the possibility of converting this project to MVC in an incremental manner. We would never get the ok from management to take the time just to convert the project in one fell swoop. It would have to be done incrementally within our business-related releases - i.e., we have releases every few months and I've been asked to explore how we could make smaller changes with each release to work our way towards MVC. Since they are 2 totally different frameworks I don't immediately see how this can be done. One idea I have is to carve out the UI piece, put that into an MVC project, and have the controllers call down to the DAL that we have now. Can you even have a solution with different project types in it? Any other ideas?

Comment: Nice discussion here: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntegratingASPNETMVC3IntoExistingUpgradedASPNET4WebFormsApplications.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar in recent past. I have a running application developed in ASP .Net and Oracle. That application has several performance issues due to which we have to re factor that. And we all agreed that we should migrate it to MVC at the same time.

So, I created a new project MVCWebClient. In that new project we created our pages one by one. Now user use old application's login page to log into our application and we changed the links which point to our new application.

Everything is working smoothly except session. Because we stored uid/pwd in session, so I created a dummy page which transfer the session parameters to our MVC application.

For example my existing application has following URLS:-

/Login.aspx

/Home.aspx

/Finance/Payslip.aspx

and I created a integration page to transfer session like this
/Integration.aspx?urlRequest=/MVCApp/Finance/Payslip

and my main navigation links become like this
/Login.aspx

/Home.aspx

/Integration.aspx?urlRequest=/MVCApp/Finance/Payslip

Feel free to ask details if you are interested in my solution.